# My android game is not visible on market for Motorola Droid

Tags: android

I have published my game for various android devices using Multiple APK submission in Android market, but few of the devices like Motorola Droid are not visible in the market. Even though the same density file as well as higher density APK is also submitted. Can any one modify/provide the Android manifest.

I have pasted my Android  manifest file here

```
<supports-screens
              android:xlargeScreens="false" 
              android:largeScreens="false"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:smallScreens="false"
              android:anyDensity="true" />
  <compatible-screens>   
  <!-- all normal size screens -->        
  <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />  
  </compatible-screens>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
android:largeScreens="false"
```

needs to be:

```
android:largeScreens="true"
```

After uploading the new apk, you will have to wait until the Android Market picks up the change before it will start to show in the filtered Motorola Droid Market listing.